# Why just yesterday?

Tags: discussion

I only recently topped 25k, but it was *less recent* than was my award of the *View Site Analytics* privilege. How come?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's a new privilege, created very recently.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260849/270345) I crossed 25k on another site long ago, but got the privilege yesterday.